# Microsoft Visual Studio Community Windows: c++ code to .DLL, .so and .dylib

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, shared-libraries, dylib

I've created in Microsoft Visual Studio Community for Windows a series of functions written in c++, with a dependency to a file to manage SQLite3 databases known as "sqlite3.c" (can be downloaded from the SQLite3 website).

I've been able to compile my code to a .DLL for x64 systems, but I'm stuck in the process to recompile for .so (Linux) and .dylib (Mac).

From Microsoft Visual Studio Community for Windows, I would like to create the .so file. I think this is possible as I've been seeing in some forums that people have managed to do it, but they don't explain the full process of how they achieved it. What would be the full process to create a .so file from Microsoft Visual Studio Community for Windows? If this is not possible... what would be the right process to do it?

Also I'm interested in creating a .dylib, but it seems that it can't be done from Microsoft Visual Studio Community for Windows, instead it has to be done through XCode in a Mac, am I right? What would be the full process to create a .dylib?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/configure-a-linux-project?view=msvc-170 https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/using-visual-studio-for-cross-platform-c-development-targeting-windows-and-linux/